# Counting of zero-modes in conifold theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, ads-cft, quantum-anomalies, instantons

I was reading [Klebanov and Witten's paper on the conifold theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9807080) and at page 11 they state that

> [...] In an instanton field of the first $U(N)$ with instanton number $k$, the gluinos of the first $U(N)$ have $2kN$ zero modes, while $A,B$ have $2kN$ each, so the path integral transforms under $\Upsilon$ as $i^{2kN}(-i)^{4kN}$, so is invariant only if $Nk$ is even.

where they are discussing the possibility of the operation $\Upsilon$ to have an anomaly.

I don't understand how they count zero modes, if somebody could elucidate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\D}{\mathrm{D}}\newcommand{\ker}{\operatorname{ker}}\newcommand{\ind}{\operatorname{ind}}\newcommand{\dim}{\operatorname{dim}}$To count the zero-modes of an operator, you must, well, look at its kernel. In this case, the relevant operator is a Dirac operator, $\D_*$, in the presense of an instanton. You can show the two following cute facts:

1. $\ker \overline{\D_*}=0$, in the background of an instanton.
2. $\ker\D_* = \ker\overline{\D_*}\D_*$, where $\overline{\D_*}$ is the adjoint of $\D_*$ (under the inner-product that defines the action).

With the first fact, you can write
\begin{align}\#(\text{zero-modes}) &:= \dim\ker\D_* = \dim\ker\D_*-\dim\ker\overline{\D_*} =: \\ 
&= \dim\ker\D_*-\dim\operatorname{coker}\D_* =: \ind\D_*.
\end{align}
With the second fact you can write
$$\ind\D_* = \ind\overline{\D_*}\D_*.$$
Therefore you need to look at the index of the square of the Dirac operator. Here you can either immeadiately use the [Atiyah-Singer index theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem), or you can prove a physicist version of it, i.e. you can go on to show that it is given by the difference of the traces of the heat-kernels:
$$\ind\overline{\D_*}\D_* = \operatorname{tr}\mathrm{e}^{-s \overline{\D_*}\D_*} - \operatorname{tr}\mathrm{e}^{-s \D_*\overline{\D_*}},$$
and since it is independent of the parameter $s$ can be evaluated at the limit $s\to 0$, giving precisely
$$\ind\overline{\D_*}\D_* = 2 (\operatorname{tr}T_aT_b)\left(\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int \operatorname{tr}F\wedge F\right) = 2 N k,$$
in the $N$ representation of $U(N)$, with $k$ being the instanton number.

For more information and justification of some of my formulas, [these lecture notes on instantons](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.1862) by Vandoren and van Nieuwenhuizen are quite useful.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!